# validation of radio buttons using groupname

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have got radiobuttons and i put them under a group name "membership". Can i use that groupname to know whether  atleast one of the radiobutton is checked on submit button click?. I dont have a form name as i have used master pages.I want to reduce the number of lines of code. Just want to know if that is possible. A small clue how to implement will help. Thanks

Comment: Provide your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a RadioButtonList?

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns = "3">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: i have like 9 radiobuttons and i have to placethem in 3x3 row-column format. if we take radiobutton list then we cannot get in that format?

Comment: You didn't say that in your post. Read up on RadioButtonList.  Look at `RepeatColumns` and `RepeatLayout`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatcolumns(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sure. I may want to use the particular radio button ID later.  Using that particular ID i create session and disable few controls. Is it possible to do without radiobutton list.